# Dialogflow Google actions - Can I have slot in welcome intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to build a simple voice app. I can do something like below with google actions SDK.

User : "Talk to Silly name maker"
Response : "Dom"

Can I build something like below:
User : "Ask to Silly name maker two names"
Response : "Dom and Bom"

Note:
I want the interaction in one shot, and for that I need to know the number of names slot in the welcome intent. I tried setting the slots in the welcome intent, but it does not recognize the number of names in the intent.

Any ideas on how to make the welcome intent recognize slots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The welcome intent doesn't support slots, but you can create a new intent with parameters and allow users to directly go to that intent if you configure it in your Integration settings.